# How to create E-Commerce websites related products slider in php

Tags: javascript, php, slider, e-commerce

I created an E-Commerce website using PHP and I want to create a related products slider. What is the best way to make that slider?

This is my sample coding:

```
<?php
$select = mysql_query("select * from product where categories ='$categories' limit 4");

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
    $p_id = $rows['product_id'];
    $p_img = $rows['image'];
    $p_color = $rows['color'];
    $p_name = $rows['product_name'];
    $p_desc = $rows['product_detsils'];
    $categories = $rows['categories'];
    $p_offer = $rows['offer'];
    $p_price = $rows['buying_price'];

//**** related products slider here ****//

}
?>
```

Comment: Didn't you try anything yet? Give your code here.

Comment: yes i tried but its not working

Comment: Please avoid using `mysql_query` etc. functions - they are deprecated: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: ya ok thank you Chayan

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="item active">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="product.php?product_id=<?php echo $p_id; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333;">
                                <img src="images/<?php echo $p_img;?>.jpg" alt="products"  />

                            <div class="caption">
                                <p style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $p_name;?></p>
                                <p style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $p_desc;?></p>
                                </a>
                                <center>
                                    <input class="add-cart btn btn-warning btn-sm" type="button" value="Add Cart" />
                                </center>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </ul>

                </div><!--item active end-->
```